# Check a URL exists in ASP.NET with timeout

Tags: asp.net, url, load-balancing

I have 5 sites and a domain like x.company.com.
I want use x.company.com as a load balancer to send users to x1 .. x5 sub domains.

before send users to special sub domain I want check sub domain services is alive.

Now I do these but check of sub domain maybe too late to response, so I want 
check sub domain service for 2 second and if no responses go to check another sub domain.

How to do that with c# asp.net?
or anybody have better suggestions for this balancing?

Comment: How are you calling the new page, with JS or what?  Code please.

Comment: You can increase the timeout for the particular page in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

My code for check URL is:

```
private bool HttpExists(string url)
{
    // If the url does not contain Http. Add it.
    if (!url.Contains("http://"))
    {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```